# logstash - Conditionally converts field types

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I inherited a logstash config as follows. I do not want to do major changes in this because I do not want to break anything that is working. The metrics are sent as logs with json in format -  "metric": "metricname", "value": "int". This has been working great. However, there is a requirement to have a string in value for a new metric. It is not really a metric but to indicate the state of the processing in string.  Based on the following filter, it converts everything to integer and any string in value will be converted to 0. The requirement is that if the value is a string, it shouldn't attempt convert. Thank you!

```
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }

    filter {
        grok {
           match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts} - M_%{DATA:task}_%{NUMBER:thread} - INFO - %{GREEDYDATA:jmetric}"}
           remove_field => [ "message", "ecs", "original", "agent", "log", "host", "path" ]
           break_on_match => false
        }

        if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
            drop {}
        }

        date {
           match => ["ts", "ISO8601"]
           target => "@timestamp"
        }

        json {
            source => "jmetric"
            remove_field => "jmetric" 
        } 

        split {
            field => "points"
            add_field => {
                "metric" => "%{[points][metric]}"
                "value" => "%{[points][value]}"
            }
            remove_field => [ "points", "event", "tags", "ts", "stream", "input" ]
        }

        mutate {
            convert => { "value" => "integer" }
            convert => { "thread" => "integer" }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you send a sample of json data parsed, please?

Comment: input splits  as follows:

```     {
                "_index": "idx-2022.03",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "rmKdmn8BJd4N7UBo-S_N",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "task": "18-mar-22--667e--10-32-1-200--dir1",
                    "@timestamp": "2022-03-18T01:21:51.510Z",
                    "@version": "1",
                    "value": 0,
                    "metric": "TotalSoftErrors",
                    "thread": 0
                }
            },
trying to add a new "metric" with a value of string

Comment: I tried to change it to the following for convert part to avoid converting the new metric. But, it is not working. 

        if [metric] != "newStringMetric" {
          mutate {
              convert => { "value" => "integer" }
              convert => { "thread" => "integer" }
          }
        }

Comment: Are you concerned about the type in logstash or the type in elasticsearch? If you have dynamic mapping enabled and the field type has been set due to [numeric detection](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#numeric-detection) then the value in es will be long/float. In that case I think it would get a mapping exception. [This thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-stores-string-in-numeric-long-field/264102/6?u=badger) may help you.

Comment: I am concerned about the data type in ES. it was due to dynamic mapping i guess. I deleted the index and it is working fine now.  The system was originally designed to handle only numeric metrics and the change required to present additional information to the users which is not really a metric but information fields in ES. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use index mappings for this mainly.
Even if you handle things in logstash, elasticsearch will - if configured with the defaults - do dynamic mapping, which may work against any configuration you do in logstash.

See [Elasticsearch index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html)

> An index template is a way to tell Elasticsearch how to configure an index when it is created.
> ...
> Index templates can contain a collection of component templates, as well as directly specify settings, mappings, and aliases.

Mappings are **pr index**! This means that when you apply new mapping, you will have to create a new index. You can "rollover" to a new index, or delete / import your data again. What you do depends on your data, how you receive it, etc. ymmv...

No matter what, if your index has the wrong mapping you will need to create a new index to get the new mapping.

PS! If you have a lot of legacy data take a look at the `reindex` API for elasticsearch.